# String Class Error, can't be added in Class

Tags: c++

String class not working in my computer ? This is my code, i hate to create a project over it , is there any syntax error, my book has used exactly like this, whats the problem ?

```
#include <string>
#ifndef LAB_PROJECT_H
#define LAB_PROJECT_H


struct Node
{
  Node* nextptr;
  Node* prevptr;
  string student_name;
  string father_name;
  int registration;
  string section;
  string major;
 string area;
 };
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? Always post the errors you get.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use fully qualified name for `string` for example.

```
std::string student_name;
```

Comment: @AsadIrfan - no, you should use the **fully qualified name** `std::string`. 'using namespace std;` is an abomination. It makes namespaces pointless.